# How to optimize boost heaps to outperform std multiset in heap operations? C++

Tags: performance, c++11, boost, binary-search-tree, heap

I have worked on implementing the fast marching method. It's a computational method to solve a special type of differential equation. In particular, this code solves the equation $$|\nabla phi| = 1$$ for $$\phi$$ given a boundary condition where $$\phi = 0$$. Anyways, to achieve a O(n lg n) running time requires the use of a priority queue supporting get_min(), extract_min(), decrease_key() and insert() (or push()). Moreover, the algorithm in question will use n insert() operations, n extract_min() operations and at worst 4n decrease_key() operations. Now, it would seem to me that heap such as the fibonacci_heap in the boost library would outperform an std set by a lot which supports the same operations (decrease key is implemented by erasing the element and readding it). However, this is not the case and I was wondering why?

(I would like to note that it is not possible to use the std priority_queue, as it does not support decrease_key())

Here is the code using a d-ary-heap:

```
#include <vector> 
#include <limits>
#include <set>
#include <tuple>
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <cassert>
#include <boost/heap/d_ary_heap.hpp>

using namespace boost::heap;

// Define epsilon value
#define EPS 0.0000000001

using namespace boost::heap;

struct treedist {
    double d;
    int row;
    int col;
    int ts;
    int known;
    bool operator<(const treedist& rhs) const
    {
        if (d == rhs.d) {
            if (known == rhs.known) {
                return ts > rhs.ts;
            }
            return known < rhs.known;
        }
        return d > rhs.d;
    }
};

struct fmmdist {
    int state;
    double d = -1;
    typename d_ary_heap<treedist,mutable_<true>,arity<2> >::handle_type it;
};

// Matrix representing state of point in fast marching method
std::vector<std::vector <fmmdist> > V;

// Binary tree used to efficiently store the distances
d_ary_heap<treedist,mutable_<true>,arity<2> > distances;

// phi array
std::vector<std::vector<double> > phi;

// Size of grid
int rows; int columns;

// Spatial step
double ddx;

const int dx[4] = {0,1,0,-1};
const int dy[4] = {1,0,-1,0};

// initialize phi array for testing purposes
void initPhi() {
    ddx = 0.001;
    rows = 16001;
    columns = 16001;
    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++ ) {
        std::vector<double> temp;
        phi.push_back(temp);
        for (int j = 0; j < columns; j++) {
            phi[i].push_back(sqrt(powf(-8 + ddx*i,2) + powf(-8 + ddx*j,2)) - 4);
        }
    }
}

// Initialize the state array
void initState() {
    // 0 means far, 1 means close, 2 means known
    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
        std::vector<fmmdist> temp;
        V.push_back(temp);
        for (int j = 0; j < columns; j++) {
            struct fmmdist f;
            f.state = 0;
            V[i].push_back(f);
        }
    }
}

// return largest root of quadratic with coef. a, b, c
// This assumes delta >= 0 (this holds for FMM method)
double quadratic(double a, double b, double c) {
    double delta = b * b - 4 * a * c;
    if ( delta > 0 ) {
        double r1 = (-b + std::sqrtf(delta))/(2*a);
        double r2 = (-b - std::sqrtf(delta))/(2*a);
        if (r1 > r2) {
            return r1;
        } 
        return r2;
    }
    return -b/(2*a);
}

// Initialization of the fast marching method
void initialization(bool inside) {
    // 0 means far, 1 means close, 2 means known
    // inside means we tag the points within the interface as known
    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < columns; j++) {
            if (inside) {
                if (phi[i][j] < EPS) { // bound used to be used here...
                    V[i][j].state = 2;
                    V[i][j].d = 0;
                } 
            } else {
                if (phi[i][j] > -EPS) {
                    V[i][j].state = 2;
                    V[i][j].d = 0;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    // find initial close points
    // see paper by sethian
    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < columns; j++) {
            if (V[i][j].state != 2) {
                int neigh = 0; // mod 16 this represents a specific configuration
                double dist = 0;
                int known = 0;
                std::vector<double> ndist;
                for (int k = 0; k < 4; k++) {
                    if (i + dx[k] >= rows || i + dx[k] < 0 || j + dy[k] >= columns || j + dy[k] < 0) continue;
                    if (V[i + dx[k]][j + dy[k]].state == 2) {
                        neigh += pow(2,k);
                        known++;
                        ndist.push_back(abs(phi[i][j]) * ddx/(abs(phi[i][j]) + abs(phi[i + dx[k]][j + dy[k]])) );
                        
                    } 
                }
                if (ndist.size() == 1) {
                    // case a
                    dist = ndist[0];
                } else if (neigh == 3 || neigh == 12 || neigh == 6 || neigh == 9) {
                    // case b
                    dist = quadratic(2,0,-(ndist[0] * ndist[0] * ndist[1] * ndist[1])/(ndist[0] * ndist[0] + ndist[1] * ndist[1]));
                } else if (neigh == 5 || neigh == 10) {
                    // case d
                    dist = fmin(ndist[0],ndist[1]);
                } else if (neigh == 13) {
                    // case c, both vertical
                    double v = fmin(ndist[0],ndist[1]);
                    dist = quadratic(2,0,-(ndist[2] * ndist[2] * v * v)/(ndist[2] * ndist[2] + v*v));
                } else if (neigh == 7) {
                    // case c, both vertical
                    double v = fmin(ndist[0],ndist[2]);
                    dist = quadratic(2,0,-(ndist[1] * ndist[1] * v * v)/(ndist[1] * ndist[1] + v*v));
                } else if (neigh == 11) {
                    // case c, both horizontal
                    double v = fmin(ndist[1],ndist[2]);
                    dist = quadratic(2,0,-(ndist[0] * ndist[0] * v * v)/(ndist[0] * ndist[0] + v*v));
                } else if (neigh == 14) {
                    // case c, both horizontal
                    double v = fmin(ndist[0],ndist[2]);
                    dist = quadratic(2,0,-(ndist[1] * ndist[1] * v * v)/(ndist[1] * ndist[1] + v*v));
                } else if (neigh == 15) {
                    // case e
                    double v = fmin(ndist[0],ndist[2]);
                    double h = fmin(ndist[1],ndist[3]);
                    dist = quadratic(2,0,-(h * h * v * v)/(h * h + v*v));
                }
                if (neigh > 0) {
                    // add to narrow band
                    struct treedist t;
                    t.d = dist; t.row = i; t.col = j; t.ts = 0; t.known = known;
                    V[i][j].state = 1;
                    V[i][j].d = dist;
                    V[i][j].it = distances.push(t); 
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

// Determine x coefficients of backward/forward difference 
std::tuple<double, double, double> rowCoef(int row, int column, bool backward) {
    int row1; 
    if (backward) {
        row1 = row - 1; 
    } else {
        row1 = row + 1; 
    }
    return std::make_tuple(1.0, -2.0 * V[row1][column].d, V[row1][column].d * V[row1][column].d );
}

// Determine y coefficients of backward/forward difference 
std::tuple<double, double, double> columnCoef(int row, int column, bool backward) {
    int col1;
    if (backward) {
        col1 = column - 1; 
    } else {
        col1 = column + 1; 
    }
    return std::make_tuple(1.0, -2.0 * V[row][col1].d, V[row][col1].d * V[row][col1].d );       
}

double computeDist(int row, int column) {
    // Determine the x-coefficients
    std::tuple<double, double, double> coefx = std::make_tuple(0,0,0);
    if (row + 1 < rows && row - 1 >= 0 ) {
        if(V[row + 1][column].state == 2 && V[row - 1][column].state == 2) coefx = rowCoef(row, column, V[row - 1][column].d < V[row + 1][column].d);
        else if (V[row + 1][column].state == 2 ) coefx = rowCoef(row, column, false);
        else if (V[row - 1][column].state == 2) coefx = rowCoef(row, column, true);
    } else if ( row + 1 < rows) {
        if(V[row + 1][column].state == 2) coefx = rowCoef(row, column, false);
    } else if ( row - 1 >= 0) {
        if(V[row - 1][column].state == 2) coefx = rowCoef(row, column, true);
    }
    // Determine the y-coefficients
    std::tuple<double, double, double> coefy = std::make_tuple(0,0,0);
    if (column + 1 < columns && column - 1 >= 0) {
        if (V[row][column + 1].state == 2 && V[row][column - 1].state == 2) coefy = columnCoef(row, column, V[row][column - 1].d < V[row][column + 1].d);
        else if (V[row][column + 1].state == 2) coefy = columnCoef(row, column, false);
        else if (V[row][column - 1].state == 2 ) coefy = columnCoef(row, column, true);
    } else if ( column + 1 < columns) {
        if(V[row][column + 1].state == 2) coefy = columnCoef(row, column, false);
    } else if ( column - 1 >= 0){
        if(V[row][column - 1].state == 2) coefy = columnCoef(row, column, true);
    } 

    // return the largest root of the quadratic
    double a = std::get<0>(coefx) + std::get<0>(coefy);
    double b = std::get<1>(coefx) + std::get<1>(coefy);
    double c = std::get<2>(coefx) + std::get<2>(coefy) - powf(ddx,2);
    double result = quadratic(a,b,c);
    assert(!isnan(result));
    return result;
}

// Fast marching loop including simultaneous velocity extension
void loopFMVel() {
    int count = 1;
    while(distances.size() > 0) {
        // extract closest
        struct treedist temp = distances.top();
        int row = temp.row; int column = temp.col;
        distances.pop();
        V[row][column].state = 2;
        for (int k = 0; k < 4; k++) {
            if (row + dx[k] >= rows || row + dx[k] < 0 || column + dy[k] >= columns || column + dy[k] < 0) continue;
            if (V[row + dx[k]][column + dy[k]].state == 2) continue;
            double d;
            if (V[row + dx[k]][column + dy[k]].state == 1) {
                d = computeDist(row + dx[k], column + dy[k]);
                if (d < (*V[row + dx[k]][column + dy[k]].it).d) {
                    (*V[row + dx[k]][column + dy[k]].it).d = d;
                    (*V[row + dx[k]][column + dy[k]].it).known = (*V[row + dx[k]][column + dy[k]].it).known + 1;
                    V[row + dx[k]][column + dy[k]].d = d;
                    distances.increase(V[row + dx[k]][column + dy[k]].it);
                }
            } else if (V[row + dx[k]][column + dy[k]].state == 0) {
                d = computeDist(row + dx[k], column + dy[k]);
                struct treedist t;
                t.d = d; t.row = row + dx[k]; t.col = column + dy[k]; t.ts = count; t.known = 1;
                V[row + dx[k]][column + dy[k]].state = 1;
                V[row + dx[k]][column + dy[k]].d = d;
                V[row + dx[k]][column + dy[k]].it = distances.push(t);
            }
        }
        count++;
    }
}

int main() {
    distances.reserve(pow(2056,2)); 
    initPhi();
    initState();
    std::cout << "Finished state init " << std::endl;
    initialization(true);
    std::cout << "Finished init of FMM " << std::endl;
    loopFMVel();
    return 0;
}
```

Here is code using a multiset:

```
#include <vector> 
#include <limits>
#include <set>
#include <tuple>
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <cassert>

// Define epsilon value
#define EPS 0.0000000001

struct treedist {
    double d;
    int row;
    int col;
    int ts;
    int known;
    bool operator<(const treedist& rhs) const
    {
        if (d == rhs.d) {
            if (known == rhs.known) {
                return ts < rhs.ts;
            }
            return known > rhs.known;
        }
        return d < rhs.d;
    }
};

struct fmmdist {
    int state;
    double d = -1;
    std::multiset<treedist>::iterator it;
};

// Matrix representing state of point in fast marching method
std::vector<std::vector <fmmdist> > V;

// Binary tree used to efficiently store the distances
std::multiset<treedist> distances;

// phi array
std::vector<std::vector<double> > phi;

// Size of grid
int rows; int columns;

// Spatial step
double ddx;

const int dx[4] = {0,1,0,-1};
const int dy[4] = {1,0,-1,0};

// initialize phi array for testing purposes
void initPhi() {
    ddx = 0.001;
    rows = 16001;
    columns = 16001;
    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++ ) {
        std::vector<double> temp;
        phi.push_back(temp);
        for (int j = 0; j < columns; j++) {
            phi[i].push_back(sqrt(powf(-8 + ddx*i,2) + powf(-8 + ddx*j,2)) - 4);
        }
    }
}

// Initialize the state array
void initState() {
    // 0 means far, 1 means close, 2 means known
    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
        std::vector<fmmdist> temp;
        V.push_back(temp);
        for (int j = 0; j < columns; j++) {
            struct fmmdist f;
            f.state = 0;
            V[i].push_back(f);
        }
    }
}

// return largest root of quadratic with coef. a, b, c
double quadratic(double a, double b, double c) {
    double delta = b * b - 4 * a * c;
    if ( delta > 0 ) {
        double r1 = (-b + std::sqrtf(delta))/(2*a);
        double r2 = (-b - std::sqrtf(delta))/(2*a);
        if (r1 > r2) {
            return r1;
        } 
        return r2;
    }
    return -b/(2*a);
}

// Initialization of the fast marching method
void initialization(bool inside) {
    // 0 means far, 1 means close, 2 means known
    // inside means we tag the points within the interface as known
    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < columns; j++) {
            if (inside) {
                if (phi[i][j] < EPS) { // bound used to be used here...
                    V[i][j].state = 2;
                    V[i][j].d = 0;
                } 
            } else {
                if (phi[i][j] > -EPS) {
                    V[i][j].state = 2;
                    V[i][j].d = 0;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    // find initial close points
    // see paper by sethian
    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < columns; j++) {
            if (V[i][j].state != 2) {
                int neigh = 0; // mod 16 this represents a specific configuration
                double dist = 0;
                int known = 0;
                std::vector<double> ndist;
                for (int k = 0; k < 4; k++) {
                    if (i + dx[k] >= rows || i + dx[k] < 0 || j + dy[k] >= columns || j + dy[k] < 0) continue;
                    if (V[i + dx[k]][j + dy[k]].state == 2) {
                        neigh += pow(2,k);
                        known++;
                        ndist.push_back(abs(phi[i][j]) * ddx/(abs(phi[i][j]) + abs(phi[i + dx[k]][j + dy[k]])) );
                        
                    } 
                }
                if (ndist.size() == 1) {
                    // case a
                    dist = ndist[0];
                } else if (neigh == 3 || neigh == 12 || neigh == 6 || neigh == 9) {
                    // case b
                    dist = quadratic(2,0,-(ndist[0] * ndist[0] * ndist[1] * ndist[1])/(ndist[0] * ndist[0] + ndist[1] * ndist[1]));
                } else if (neigh == 5 || neigh == 10) {
                    // case d
                    dist = fmin(ndist[0],ndist[1]);
                } else if (neigh == 13) {
                    // case c, both vertical
                    double v = fmin(ndist[0],ndist[1]);
                    dist = quadratic(2,0,-(ndist[2] * ndist[2] * v * v)/(ndist[2] * ndist[2] + v*v));
                } else if (neigh == 7) {
                    // case c, both vertical
                    double v = fmin(ndist[0],ndist[2]);
                    dist = quadratic(2,0,-(ndist[1] * ndist[1] * v * v)/(ndist[1] * ndist[1] + v*v));
                } else if (neigh == 11) {
                    // case c, both horizontal
                    double v = fmin(ndist[1],ndist[2]);
                    dist = quadratic(2,0,-(ndist[0] * ndist[0] * v * v)/(ndist[0] * ndist[0] + v*v));
                } else if (neigh == 14) {
                    // case c, both horizontal
                    double v = fmin(ndist[0],ndist[2]);
                    dist = quadratic(2,0,-(ndist[1] * ndist[1] * v * v)/(ndist[1] * ndist[1] + v*v));
                } else if (neigh == 15) {
                    // case e
                    double v = fmin(ndist[0],ndist[2]);
                    double h = fmin(ndist[1],ndist[3]);
                    dist = quadratic(2,0,-(h * h * v * v)/(h * h + v*v));
                }
                if (neigh > 0) {
                    // add to narrow band
                    struct treedist t;
                    t.d = dist; t.row = i; t.col = j; t.ts = 0; t.known = known;
                    V[i][j].state = 1;
                    V[i][j].d = dist;
                    V[i][j].it = distances.insert(t); 
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

// Determine x coefficients of backward/forward difference 
std::tuple<double, double, double> rowCoef(int row, int column, bool backward) {
    int row1; 
    if (backward) {
        row1 = row - 1; 
    } else {
        row1 = row + 1;
    }
    return std::make_tuple(1.0, -2.0 * V[row1][column].d, V[row1][column].d * V[row1][column].d );
}

// Determine y coefficients of backward/forward difference 
std::tuple<double, double, double> columnCoef(int row, int column, bool backward) {
    int col1; 
    if (backward) {
        col1 = column - 1; 
    } else {
        col1 = column + 1; 
    }
    return std::make_tuple(1.0, -2.0 * V[row][col1].d, V[row][col1].d * V[row][col1].d );       
}


double computeDist(int row, int column) {
    // Determine the x-coefficients
    std::tuple<double, double, double> coefx = std::make_tuple(0,0,0);
    if (row + 1 < rows && row - 1 >= 0 ) {
        if(V[row + 1][column].state == 2 && V[row - 1][column].state == 2) coefx = rowCoef(row, column, V[row - 1][column].d < V[row + 1][column].d);
        else if (V[row + 1][column].state == 2 ) coefx = rowCoef(row, column, false);
        else if (V[row - 1][column].state == 2) coefx = rowCoef(row, column, true);
    } else if ( row + 1 < rows) {
        if(V[row + 1][column].state == 2) coefx = rowCoef(row, column, false);
    } else if ( row - 1 >= 0) {
        if(V[row - 1][column].state == 2) coefx = rowCoef(row, column, true);
    }
    // Determine the y-coefficients
    std::tuple<double, double, double> coefy = std::make_tuple(0,0,0);
    if (column + 1 < columns && column - 1 >= 0) {
        if (V[row][column + 1].state == 2 && V[row][column - 1].state == 2) coefy = columnCoef(row, column, V[row][column - 1].d < V[row][column + 1].d);
        else if (V[row][column + 1].state == 2) coefy = columnCoef(row, column, false);
        else if (V[row][column - 1].state == 2 ) coefy = columnCoef(row, column, true);
    } else if ( column + 1 < columns) {
        if(V[row][column + 1].state == 2) coefy = columnCoef(row, column, false);
    } else if ( column - 1 >= 0){
        if(V[row][column - 1].state == 2) coefy = columnCoef(row, column, true);
    } 
    // return the largest root of the quadratic
    double a = std::get<0>(coefx) + std::get<0>(coefy);
    double b = std::get<1>(coefx) + std::get<1>(coefy);
    double c = std::get<2>(coefx) + std::get<2>(coefy) - powf(ddx,2);

    double result = quadratic(a,b,c);
    return result;
}

// Fast marching loop i
void loopFMVel() {
    int count = 1;
    while(distances.size() > 0) {
        // extract closest
        std::multiset<treedist>::iterator it = distances.begin();
        int row = (*it).row; int column = (*it).col;
        distances.erase(it);
        V[row][column].state = 2;
        for (int k = 0; k < 4; k++) {
            if (row + dx[k] >= rows || row + dx[k] < 0 || column + dy[k] >= columns || column + dy[k] < 0) continue;
            if (V[row + dx[k]][column + dy[k]].state == 2) continue;
            double d;
            if (V[row + dx[k]][column + dy[k]].state == 1) {
                d = computeDist(row + dx[k], column + dy[k]);
                struct treedist t;
                t.d = (*V[row + dx[k]][column + dy[k]].it).d; t.known = (*V[row + dx[k]][column + dy[k]].it).known;
                t.known++;
                t.row = row + dx[k]; t.col = column + dy[k]; t.ts = (*V[row + dx[k]][column + dy[k]].it).ts;
                if (d < t.d) {
                    t.d = d;
                    V[row + dx[k]][column + dy[k]].d = d;
                }
                distances.erase(V[row + dx[k]][column + dy[k]].it);
                V[row + dx[k]][column + dy[k]].it = distances.insert(t);
            } else if (V[row + dx[k]][column + dy[k]].state == 0) {
                d = computeDist(row + dx[k], column + dy[k]);
                struct treedist t;
                t.d = d; t.row = row + dx[k]; t.col = column + dy[k]; t.ts = count; t.known = 1;
                V[row + dx[k]][column + dy[k]].state = 1;
                V[row + dx[k]][column + dy[k]].d = d;
                V[row + dx[k]][column + dy[k]].it = distances.insert(t);
            }
        }
        count++;
    }
    
    std::cout << "Finished with size " << distances.size() << std::endl;
}

int main() {
    initPhi();
    initState();
    std::cout << "Finished state init " << std::endl;
    initialization(true);
    std::cout << "Finished init of FMM " << std::endl;
    loopFMVel();
    return 0;
}
```

The following are some results from my testing:

N = 16001^2 (I ran these tests on an M1 max with flags -Ofast -fno-finite-math-only -march=armv8.5-a -mcpu=native -ffast-math)
binary_heap (with reserved memory): 58.35s
multiset: 63.33s
fibonacci_heap: 73.43
16_ary_heap (with reserved memory): 65.40s
pairing_heap: 116.5s

I profiled using time. If any more details are required, I will gladly add them.

Comment: If you make a self-contained code example I'll happily (try to) optimize it for you. Right now we don't even know the types of all non-locals.

Comment: That is certainly fair... I will add a code snippet using a multiset and a daryheap. To keep it close to what it will be in the end, I cannot remove that much so it is still quite large

Comment: Constants in complexity do not matter much. The codes are a bit large so I did not analysed them carefully, but based on the provided information, it looks like both are running in `O(n log n)` time. Other factors can impact performance, including the memory access pattern (starting from cache effects, the predictability of the accesses). Not to mention there is often an hidden constant in the run-time complexity of data structures. By the way, please consider using flatten matrices instead of `std::vector<std::vector<T>>` which is known to be inefficient.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I spent an inordinate amount of time refactoring the code so I could actually understand it.

### Style/Performance

While reading through I made some changes that

- avoid repeated code or subexpressions (which are *very* error-prone especially in copy-pasted stuff)
- tried to find "meaningful" names.
- removed magic constants (if you can comment them, you can use an enum)
- avoid dynamic allocation and incremental insertions. Unless you define `USE_VECTOR` my version uses `std::array` to allocate everything up-front:

  ```
   #ifndef USE_VECTOR
       template <typename T, size_t C> using Row              = std::array<T, C>;
       template <typename T, size_t R, size_t C> using Matrix = std::array<Row<T, C>, R>;
   #else
       template <typename T, size_t R, size_t C> struct Matrix {
           std::vector<std::vector<T>> impl_;
           Matrix() : impl_(R, std::vector<T>(C, T{})) {}

           auto& operator[](size_t n) const { return impl_[n]; }
           auto& operator[](size_t n)       { return impl_[n]; }
       };
   #endif
  ```

  Which is used for both the `phi` and `V`:

  ```
   // phi array
   Matrix<double, rows, columns> phi;

   // Matrix representing state of point in fast marching method
   Matrix<fmmdist, rows, columns> V;
  ```
- avoid C-isms like `sqrtf`, prefer `std::min` over manual compare and swap
- I rewrote the branches in `initialization` to always use the same path for the `quadratic` calculation:

  ```
   double dist = pick_distance(ndist, neigh);
  ```

  Which is implemented (also using a `static_vector<double, 4>` for the max 4 neighboring distances):

  ```
   using NDist = boost::container::static_vector<double, 4>;

   static double pick_distance(NDist const& ndist, unsigned configuration)  {
       if (ndist.size() == 1)
           return ndist[0]; // case a

       auto q_hv = [](double h, double v) {
           return quadratic(2, 0, -(h * h * v * v) / (h * h + v * v));
       };

       switch (configuration) {
           case 3: case 12:
           case 6: case 9:  return q_hv(ndist[0], ndist[1]);                     // case b
           case 5: case 10: return std::min(ndist[0], ndist[1]);                 // case d
           case 13:         return q_hv(ndist[2], std::min(ndist[0], ndist[1])); // case c, both vertical
           case 7:          return q_hv(ndist[1], std::min(ndist[0], ndist[2])); // case c, both vertical
           case 11:         return q_hv(ndist[0], std::min(ndist[1], ndist[2])); // case c, both horizontal
           case 14:         return q_hv(ndist[1], std::min(ndist[0], ndist[2])); // case c, both horizontal
           case 15:         return q_hv(std::min(ndist[1], ndist[3]), std::min(ndist[0], ndist[2])); // case e
           default:         return 0;
       }
   };
  ```
- adding the bits to the `neigh` bitmask (which is a clever trick, by the way) can be done safer and more effectively:

  ```
   neigh |= (1 << k); // instead of neigh += pow(2,k);
  ```
- the various variables `known` and `ndist` all have pretty redundant state, adhering to the following invariants:

  ```
   assert(known >= 0);
   assert(std::popcount(neigh) == known);
   assert(known == static_cast<int>(ndist.size()));
   assert((neigh != 0) == (known != 0));
   assert((neigh == 0) == ndist.empty());
  ```

  I'd suggest dropping some of the unused values. With these, and extracting the repeated sub-expressions, the `initialization` function becomes much more readable:

  ```
   // Initialization of the fast marching method
   void initialization(bool inside) {
       // inside means we tag the points within the interface as known
       for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
           for (int j = 0; j < columns; j++)
               if (inside != (phi[i][j] >= EPS)) { // bound used to be used here...
                   V[i][j].state = fmmdist::known;
                   V[i][j].dist  = 0;
               }

       // find initial close points
       // see paper by James Sethian
       NDist ndist;
       for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
           for (int j = 0; j < columns; j++) {
               if (V[i][j].state != fmmdist::known) {
                   unsigned neigh = 0; // mod 16 this represents a specific configuration

                   ndist.clear();
                   for (unsigned k = 0; k < dx.size(); k++) {
                       auto const r = i + dx[k];
                       auto const c = j + dy[k];
                       if (r >= rows || r < 0 || c >= columns || c < 0)
                           continue;

                       if (V[r][c].state == fmmdist::known) {
                           neigh |= (1 << k);

                           using std::abs;
                           ndist.push_back(abs(phi[i][j]) * ddx / (abs(phi[i][j]) + abs(phi[r][c])));
                       }
                   }

                   if (neigh) {
                       double dist = pick_distance(ndist, neigh);

                       // add to narrow band
                       treedist t;
                       t.dist  = dist;
                       t.coord = {i, j};
                       t.ts    = 0;
                       t.known = ndist.size();
                       V[i][j] = {fmmdist::close, dist, queue.push(t)};
                   }
               }
           }
       }
   }
  ```
- Similar treatment of the `loopFMVel()` function has a similar effect:

  ```
   // Fast marching loop including simultaneous velocity extension
   void loopFMVel() {
       Timestamp tsclock = 1;

       while (!queue.empty()) {
           auto [row, column]   = queue.pop();
           V[row][column].state = fmmdist::known;

           for (unsigned k = 0; k < dx.size(); k++) {
               auto const r = row + dx[k];
               auto const c = column + dy[k];
               if (r >= rows || r < 0 || c >= columns || c < 0)
                   continue;

               auto& cell = V[r][c]; // TODO better name
               if (cell.state == fmmdist::known)
                   continue;

               auto dist = computeDist(r, c);
               if (cell.state == fmmdist::close) {
                   if (auto& old = *cell.handle; dist < old.dist) {
                       cell.dist = dist;
                       queue.increase(cell.handle, dist);
                   }
               } else if (cell.state == fmmdist::far) {
                   treedist temp;
                   temp.coord = {r, c};
                   temp.dist  = dist;
                   temp.known = 1;
                   temp.ts    = tsclock;

                   cell.state  = fmmdist::close;
                   cell.dist   = dist;
                   cell.handle = queue.push(temp);
               }
           }
           tsclock += 1;
       }
   }
  ```

## Issues

Along the way I spotted some potential issues:

1. Accidentally truncating floating point numbers to integers

   Did you *mean* to use `int ::abs(int)` in line 129? Fix it using `std::abs` to get `double std::abs(double)`:

   ```
   using std::abs;
   ndist.push_back(
       abs(phi[i][j]) * ddx /
       (abs(phi[i][j]) + abs(phi[i + dx[k]][j + dy[k]])));
   ```
2. Inconsistent `computeDist`. After all my review the function now reads as:

   ```
   struct Coef {
       double      a, b, c;
       static Coef make(double d) { return {1.0, -2.0 * d, d * d}; };
   };

   double computeDist(int row, int column) {
       // Determine the x-coefficients
       auto closest = [](fmmdist const* next, fmmdist const* prev) {
           if (next && next->state != fmmdist::known) next = nullptr;
           if (prev && prev->state != fmmdist::known) prev = nullptr;

           if (!(next || prev))
               return Coef{0, 0, 0}; // TODO is this okay? might need to be Coef::make(INF)?

           double d = std::numeric_limits<double>::infinity();
           if (next) d = std::min(d, next->dist);
           if (prev) d = std::min(d, prev->dist);
           return Coef::make(d);
       };

       Coef x = closest(                                   //
           row + 1 < rows ? &V[row + 1][column] : nullptr, //
           row > 0        ? &V[row - 1][column] : nullptr);
       Coef y = closest(                                         //
           column + 1 < columns ? &V[row][column + 1] : nullptr, //
           column > 0           ? &V[row][column - 1] : nullptr);

       // return the largest root of the quadratic
       double a = x.a + y.a;
       double b = x.b + y.b;
       double c = x.c + y.c - powf(ddx, 2);

       double result = quadratic(a, b, c);
       assert(!std::isnan(result));
       return result;
   }
   ```

   In this form the distinction between `rowCoef` and `columnCoef` went away. And a potential problem is highlighted:

   ```
   if (!(next || prev))
       return Coef{0, 0, 0}; // TODO is this okay? might need to be Coef::make(INF)?
   ```

   If no neighbouring row/column is accessible and in the `known`, we're defaulting to suddenly different coefficents `(0, 0, 0)`, where I'd probably have expected `(2, -Inf, Inf)` for consistency. If you agree, we can remove the special-case making the code even more elegant:

   ```
   auto closest = [](auto*... candidates) {
       double dist = INFINITY;

       for (auto p : {candidates...})
           if (p && p->state == fmmdist::known)
               dist = std::min(dist, p->dist);

       return Coef{1.0, -2.0 * dist, dist * dist};
   };
   ```
3. Comparing your versions, I note that the multiset variant behaves differently: it **always** increases `known` regardless of whether the distance is decreased.

   [image]

   > *As you've seen above, I assumed that you only want to update like in your heap implementation, to make it a fair comparison.*

### Queue Implementations

I refactored the code so I could switch the queue implementation with the same FMM implementation:

```
struct QueueConcept {
    using Handle = /*stable handle type*/;

    size_t size()  const;
    bool   empty() const;

    Coord pop(); // extract closest
    Handle push(treedist v);

    void increase(Handle& h, double dist);
};
```

Which is trivially implemented for both `multiset` and `d_ary_heap`.

```
struct DistanceTree {
    using Storage = std::multiset<treedist, treedist::Less>;
    using Handle  = typename Storage::const_iterator; // must be stable

    size_t size()  const { return _storage.size();  }
    bool   empty() const { return _storage.empty(); }

    Coord pop() { // extract closest
        Handle handle = _storage.begin();
        Coord  coord  = handle->coord;
        _storage.erase(handle);
        return coord;
    }

    Handle push(treedist v) { return _storage.insert(std::move(v)); }

    void increase(Handle& h, double dist) {
        treedist v = *h;
        _storage.erase(h);

        assert(dist <= v.dist);
        v.dist = dist;
        v.known += 1;

        h = push(std::move(v));
    }

  private:
    Storage _storage;
};

struct DistanceHeap {
    using Storage = bh::d_ary_heap<treedist, //
                                   bh::compare<treedist::Greater>, bh::mutable_<true>, bh::arity<2>>;
    using Handle  = Storage::handle_type;

    DistanceHeap() { _storage.reserve(2056 * 2056); }

    size_t size()  const { return _storage.size();  }
    bool   empty() const { return _storage.empty(); }

    Coord pop() { // extract closest
        auto& temp  = _storage.top();
        Coord  coord = temp.coord;
        _storage.pop();
        return coord;
    }

    Handle push(treedist v) { return _storage.push(std::move(v)); }

    void increase(Handle h, double dist) {
        auto& v = *h;
        assert(dist <= v.dist);
        v.dist = dist;
        v.known += 1;
        _storage.increase(h);
    }

  private:
    Storage _storage;
};
```

Now I templated the `Algorithm` code like so:

```
template <typename Queue, int rows = 16001, int columns = rows> //
struct Algorithm {
    Queue queue; // prio queue used to efficiently store the distances

    // .. the rest
};
```

And added a test-bed:

```
#include <chrono>
#include <iomanip>
namespace {
    static long elapsed() {
        auto now = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now;
        using namespace std::chrono_literals;
        static auto start = now();
        auto        t     = now();

        return (t - std::exchange(start, t)) / 1ms;
    }

    void trace(auto const&... args) {
        ((std::cout << std::setw(10) << elapsed() << "ms ") << ... << args) << std::endl;
    }

    template <typename Queue> void run() {
        trace(__PRETTY_FUNCTION__);

        auto a = std::make_unique<Algorithm<Queue, 5601>>();
        trace("Constructed");
        a->initPhi();
        a->initState();
        trace("Finished state init ");
        a->initialization(true);
        trace("Finished init of FMM ");
        a->loopFMVel();
        trace("Done");
    }
} // namespace

int main(int argc, char**) {
    std::ios::sync_with_stdio(false);
    trace("Start");
    if (argc == 1) run<DistanceTree>();
    if (argc >= 2) run<DistanceHeap>();
    if (argc == 3) run<DistanceTree>();
    trace("Exit");
}
```

## Live Demo

**[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3926888d45b41e49)**

```
#include <array>
#include <cassert>
#include <cmath>
#include <limits>
#include <memory>
#include <set>
#include <tuple>
#include <utility>
#include <vector>

#include <boost/container/static_vector.hpp>
#include <boost/heap/d_ary_heap.hpp>
namespace bh = boost::heap;

// Define epsilon value
static inline constexpr double EPS = 1e-10;

#ifndef USE_VECTOR
    template <typename T, size_t C> using Row              = std::array<T, C>;
    template <typename T, size_t R, size_t C> using Matrix = std::array<Row<T, C>, R>;
#else
    template <typename T, size_t R, size_t C> struct Matrix {
        std::vector<std::vector<T>> impl_;
        Matrix() : impl_(R, std::vector<T>(C, T{})) {}

        auto& operator[](size_t n) const { return impl_[n]; }
        auto& operator[](size_t n)       { return impl_[n]; }
    };
#endif

using Timestamp = unsigned long;

struct Coord { int row, col; };

struct treedist {
    double    dist;
    int       known;
    Timestamp ts;
    Coord     coord;

  private:
    constexpr auto key() const { // natural order by nearest, greatest known and earliest ts
        return std::tuple(dist, -known, ts);
    }

  public:
    struct Less {
        constexpr bool operator()(treedist const& a, treedist const& b) const { return a.key() < b.key(); }
    };
    struct Greater {
        constexpr bool operator()(treedist const& a, treedist const& b) const { return a.key() > b.key(); }
    };
};

struct DistanceTree {
    using Storage = std::multiset<treedist, treedist::Less>;
    using Handle  = typename Storage::const_iterator; // must be stable

    size_t size()  const { return _storage.size();  }
    bool   empty() const { return _storage.empty(); }

    Coord pop() { // extract closest
        Handle handle = _storage.begin();
        Coord  coord  = handle->coord;
        _storage.erase(handle);
        return coord;
    }

    Handle push(treedist v) { return _storage.insert(std::move(v)); }

    void increase(Handle& h, double dist) {
        treedist v = *h;
        _storage.erase(h);

        assert(dist <= v.dist);
        v.dist = dist;
        v.known += 1;

        h = push(std::move(v));
    }

  private:
    Storage _storage;
};

struct DistanceHeap {
    using Storage = bh::d_ary_heap<treedist, //
                                   bh::compare<treedist::Greater>, bh::mutable_<true>, bh::arity<2>>;
    using Handle  = Storage::handle_type;

    DistanceHeap() { _storage.reserve(2056 * 2056); }

    size_t size()  const { return _storage.size();  }
    bool   empty() const { return _storage.empty(); }

    Coord pop() { // extract closest
        auto& temp  = _storage.top();
        Coord  coord = temp.coord;
        _storage.pop();
        return coord;
    }

    Handle push(treedist v) { return _storage.push(std::move(v)); }

    void increase(Handle h, double dist) {
        auto& v = *h;
        assert(dist <= v.dist);
        v.dist = dist;
        v.known += 1;
        _storage.increase(h);
    }

  private:
    Storage _storage;
};

template <typename Queue, int rows = 16001, int columns = rows> //
struct Algorithm {
    Queue queue; // prio queue used to efficiently store the distances

    struct fmmdist {
        enum State { far = 0, close = 1, known = 2 };
        State                  state{far};
        double                 dist{-1};
        typename Queue::Handle handle{};
    };

    // phi array
    Matrix<double, rows, columns> phi;

    // Matrix representing state of point in fast marching method
    Matrix<fmmdist, rows, columns> V;

    // Spatial step
    static double constexpr ddx = 1e-3;

    static constexpr std::array<int, 4> dx{0, 1, 0, -1};
    static constexpr std::array<int, 4> dy{1, 0, -1, 0};

    // initialize phi array for testing purposes
    inline void initPhi() {
        for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
            for (int j = 0; j < columns; j++)
                phi[i][j] = sqrt(pow(-8 + ddx * i, 2) + pow(-8 + ddx * j, 2)) - 4;
    }

    // Initialize the state array
    void initState() {
        for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
            for (int j = 0; j < columns; j++)
                V[i][j] = {fmmdist::far, -1, {}};
    }

    // return largest root of quadratic with coef. a, b, c
    // This assumes delta >= 0 (this holds for FMM method)
    static double quadratic(double a, double b, double c) {
        double delta = b * b - 4 * a * c;
        if (delta > 0) {
            double r1 = (-b + std::sqrt(delta)) / (2 * a);
            double r2 = (-b - std::sqrt(delta)) / (2 * a);
            return std::max(r1, r2);
        }
        return -b / (2 * a);
    }

    using NDist = boost::container::static_vector<double, 4>;

    static double pick_distance(NDist const& ndist, unsigned configuration)  {
        if (ndist.size() == 1)
            return ndist[0]; // case a

        auto q_hv = [](double h, double v) {
            return quadratic(2, 0, -(h * h * v * v) / (h * h + v * v));
        };

        switch (configuration) {
            case 3: case 12:
            case 6: case 9:  return q_hv(ndist[0], ndist[1]);                     // case b
            case 5: case 10: return std::min(ndist[0], ndist[1]);                 // case d
            case 13:         return q_hv(ndist[2], std::min(ndist[0], ndist[1])); // case c, both vertical
            case 7:          return q_hv(ndist[1], std::min(ndist[0], ndist[2])); // case c, both vertical
            case 11:         return q_hv(ndist[0], std::min(ndist[1], ndist[2])); // case c, both horizontal
            case 14:         return q_hv(ndist[1], std::min(ndist[0], ndist[2])); // case c, both horizontal
            case 15:         return q_hv(std::min(ndist[1], ndist[3]), std::min(ndist[0], ndist[2])); // case e
            default:         return 0;
        }
    };

    // Initialization of the fast marching method
    void initialization(bool inside) {
        // inside means we tag the points within the interface as known
        for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
            for (int j = 0; j < columns; j++)
                if (inside != (phi[i][j] >= EPS)) { // bound used to be used here...
                    V[i][j].state = fmmdist::known;
                    V[i][j].dist  = 0;
                }

        // find initial close points
        // see paper by James Sethian
        NDist ndist;
        for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < columns; j++) {
                if (V[i][j].state != fmmdist::known) {
                    unsigned neigh = 0; // mod 16 this represents a specific configuration

                    ndist.clear();
                    for (unsigned k = 0; k < dx.size(); k++) {
                        auto const r = i + dx[k];
                        auto const c = j + dy[k];
                        if (r >= rows || r < 0 || c >= columns || c < 0)
                            continue;

                        if (V[r][c].state == fmmdist::known) {
                            neigh |= (1 << k);

                            using std::abs;
                            ndist.push_back(abs(phi[i][j]) * ddx / (abs(phi[i][j]) + abs(phi[r][c])));
                        }
                    }

                    if (neigh) {
                        double dist = pick_distance(ndist, neigh);

                        // add to narrow band
                        treedist t;
                        t.dist  = dist;
                        t.coord = {i, j};
                        t.ts    = 0;
                        t.known = ndist.size();
                        V[i][j] = {fmmdist::close, dist, queue.push(t)};
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    struct Coef {
        double a, b, c;
    };

    double computeDist(int row, int column) {
        // Determine the x-coefficients
        auto closest = [](auto*... candidates) {
            double dist = INFINITY;

            for (auto p : {candidates...})
                if (p && p->state == fmmdist::known)
                    dist = std::min(dist, p->dist);

            return Coef{1.0, -2.0 * dist, dist * dist};
        };

        Coef x = closest(                                   //
            row + 1 < rows ? &V[row + 1][column] : nullptr, //
            row > 0        ? &V[row - 1][column] : nullptr);
        Coef y = closest(                                         //
            column + 1 < columns ? &V[row][column + 1] : nullptr, //
            column > 0           ? &V[row][column - 1] : nullptr);

        // return the largest root of the quadratic
        double a = x.a + y.a;
        double b = x.b + y.b;
        double c = x.c + y.c - powf(ddx, 2);

        double result = quadratic(a, b, c);
        assert(!std::isnan(result));
        return result;
    }

    // Fast marching loop including simultaneous velocity extension
    void loopFMVel() {
        Timestamp tsclock = 1;

        while (!queue.empty()) {
            auto [row, column]   = queue.pop();
            V[row][column].state = fmmdist::known;

            for (unsigned k = 0; k < dx.size(); k++) {
                auto const r = row + dx[k];
                auto const c = column + dy[k];
                if (r >= rows || r < 0 || c >= columns || c < 0)
                    continue;

                auto& cell = V[r][c]; // TODO better name
                if (cell.state == fmmdist::known)
                    continue;

                auto dist = computeDist(r, c);
                if (cell.state == fmmdist::close) {
                    if (auto& old = *cell.handle; dist < old.dist) {
                        cell.dist = dist;
                        queue.increase(cell.handle, dist);
                    }
                } else if (cell.state == fmmdist::far) {
                    treedist temp;
                    temp.coord = {r, c};
                    temp.dist  = dist;
                    temp.known = 1;
                    temp.ts    = tsclock;

                    cell.state  = fmmdist::close;
                    cell.dist   = dist;
                    cell.handle = queue.push(temp);
                }
            }
            tsclock += 1;
        }
    }
};

#include <chrono>
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>
namespace {
    static long elapsed() {
        auto now = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now;
        using namespace std::chrono_literals;
        static auto start = now();
        auto        t     = now();

        return (t - std::exchange(start, t)) / 1ms;
    }

    void trace(auto const&... args) {
        ((std::cout << std::setw(10) << elapsed() << "ms ") << ... << args) << std::endl;
    }

    template <typename Queue> void run() {
        trace(__PRETTY_FUNCTION__);

        auto a = std::make_unique<Algorithm<Queue, 5601>>();
        trace("Constructed");
        a->initPhi();
        a->initState();
        trace("Finished state init ");
        a->initialization(true);
        trace("Finished init of FMM ");
        a->loopFMVel();
        trace("Done");
    }
} // namespace

int main(int argc, char**) {
    std::ios::sync_with_stdio(false);
    trace("Start");
    if (argc == 1) run<DistanceTree>();
    if (argc >= 2) run<DistanceHeap>();
    if (argc == 3) run<DistanceTree>();
    trace("Exit");
}
```

Printing [(online)](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/67740d21a4abada1):

```
g++ -std=c++20 -O3 -DNDEBUG -ffast-math -Wall -pedantic -pthread main.cpp && ./a.out heap tree

     0ms Start
     0ms void {anonymous}::run() [with Queue = DistanceHeap]
  1529ms Constructed
   263ms Finished state init 
   228ms Finished init of FMM 
 10523ms Done
   267ms void {anonymous}::run() [with Queue = DistanceTree]
  1204ms Constructed
   282ms Finished state init 
   225ms Finished init of FMM 
  8305ms Done
   262ms Exit
```

Local demo:

[image]

Comment: Just out of curiosity I provided more Matrix and Queue implementations so you might profile for bottle necks in the respective configurations. I took advantage of some  optimizations: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e4d7a3d3c6eb9d36 It is pretty clear what seems to be the winner: https://i.imgur.com/EmyGLPm.png

Comment: First off, this is certainly way more than I expected, so thank you... It clearly is much quicker than my previous implementation, although it still surprises me that the BST outperforms the heaps. Concerning your issues, 1 and 3 were certainly not intended, so it is nice that you spotted those. Issue 2 is necessary, as you do not want the coefficients when there is no neighbor in that coordinate direction.

Comment: Hah. I never even compared to the "original" code... I'm quite surprised there's [such a big speed up](https://i.imgur.com/Tuea0he.png) (that's with 16001² grid). I didn't really anticipate that. I suppose it's mostly from marking a few constants `constexpr`.

Comment: Profiling (on 5601² grid again, because it's dogslow instrumented with valgrind) revealed that it's likely allocations (down from 412m to 31m, corresponding to tree insertions). Also, `loopFMVel()` body (without children) is down from 41g to 9g instruction fetches, [amounting to 49% vs 34% of total cost respectively]. Interestingly the hinting has marginal impact, best compared [visually](https://imgur.com/Ox0gshU). Initialization appears to be [17x faster](https://imgur.com/ouglRCf) so yeah. It did some good things. You will want to review that I didn't accidentally introduce a bug myself!

Comment: Yes, I will be running some test cases (in form of differential equations with known analytical solutions) to check it is still well-behaved. Regardless, the speed increase will be extremely helpful in running simulations and given my limited knowledge of c++, it is helpful to see what can be improved stylistically

Comment: @B0bby31 I have a rogue brainwave to replace the queue datastructure with something potentially more performant. Remind me in a few days in case I forget to try it!

Comment: Oh. I did forget. My idea was to use intrusive containers to have the tree/priority queue in-place over the grid itself. There's a space/efficiency trade-off. Also in the process I think everything becamse way simpler (because there is no longer a need to store an artificial "handle-to-self" anywhere). I'll find that code in a minute and share

Comment: Hey @sehe, this project ended up becoming quite large (much more extensive then just the FMM) and I plan on open sourcing the code. Although there are only minor parts in the code base that you edited, I still wanted to ask whether you are ok with it being open sourced. I will add an acknowledgment in the relevant file indicating your contribution. (this question is somewhat rhetorical given its is an open forum, but I decided to ask anyway)

Comment: @B0bby31 Yes I'm okay with that. I'd like to see it when it goes public :)